# Check Constraint of an Attribute

Tags: sql

I'm trying to wrap my head around sql right now for a class and my question is specifically about my fourth constraint. In order to be considered a junior you need to have a set of completed hours between 55 and 84 hours. My actual error is that I'm missing a parentheses. However that is not what my question is about. I know what I have is wrong, but I'm not sure why. What I think I'm supposed to do is to call the classification and the define the type of classification relying on the hours. That is why I'm unsure of how this is supposed to be called upon. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
id INTEGER,
name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
classification CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
hours INTEGER,
gpa NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL,
mentor INTEGER,
-- IC4:
-- To be classified as a 'junior',a student must have
-- completed between 55 and 84 hours (inclusive).
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification IN(classification = 'junior' AND hours >= 55 AND hours <= 84)),
```

Comment: Unrelated but: `char` is almost never a good choice. Use `varchar` instead

Comment: I'm sure you're right in general, however due to the nature of the assignment, I'm not allowed to change that section at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn it around a little. Only for juniors you should check hours, i.e. for non-juniors, the hours doesn't matter.

```
check(classification <> 'junior' or hours between 55 and 84)
```